# Bundled Items not going out of stock when a component is out of stock

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-2.2.5, bundled-product

What needs to be set for a bundle product to go out of stock if one of it's components goes out of stock?

Right now I have a bundle product with manage stock set to yes. Ship together. Input type multiple select, required checked.

Three products, qty 1 all have default checked.

If one of those three products goes out of stock, the bundle remains in stock and can be purchased not including the out of stock product. How can I change this to where if one product is out of stock, the entire bundle is marked as out of stock?

Magento 2.2.5

Comment: Also looking for a solution to this. I need bundled or grouped items to be marked out of stock if any of the child items are out of stock. I don't understand the logic.